# mutiplication on woocommerce variable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to multiply the price by 1.2, this is my code, but the result is unsuccessful, numbers are missing.

For example of $12900 the result is $4335 (the result is not right)

The right result is: $12900 x 1.12 = $15.480

Screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/ita29v

My Code:

```
<?php echo '$' . round((preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $product->get_price_html()) * 1.2), 0); ?>
```

```html
<div id="listadeprecio">
 <div id="preciointernet">
  
<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
Efectivo, Transferencia, Depósito Bancario
 </div>
</br>
 <div id="preciocredito">
  <div class="credito" style="color: black; font-size: 22px;"><?php echo '$' . round((preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $product->get_price_html()) * 1.2), 0); ?> (beta)</div>
  Precio WebPay T. Debito/Credito</br>
  <img src="https://jumpseller.cl/images/gateways/gateway_webpay.jpg" alt="WebPay Plus" height="42" style="max-height: 75px;">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like `get_price_html` returns more than the actual price as a number based on the method name.

Comment: @HeinAndreGrønnestad yeah, but I believe that the multiplication code is done in another way ...

Comment: I see that the regex is trying to remove the other data, show us the output of `preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $product->get_price_html())`.

Comment: Try to store the price in a variable : `<p class="price"><?php $price = $product->get_price_html(); echo $price; ?></p>`
And then use the `$price` in the `round()`...

Comment: @HeinAndreGrønnestad this code shows the product price with Sale Price, my original code shows only the final price of the product :(

Comment: Are you sure of your `$product->get_price_html()` value? When I test I get 15480: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/30ec652171955ca75659ead3bd5493b5bb54791f

Comment: @Hammerbot Finnaly i fixed removing "_html" and works! `<?php echo '$' . round((preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $product->get_price()) *1.2)); ?>` but the result is not formatted with points... i want to show "15.480" not "15480" you know something?